# Ubuntu resets sessions after resumes from suspend

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, hibernate, 21.10

My Ubuntu was working fine earlier and then I installed GPU drivers as mentioned on [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu*+). After the drivers are installed, whenever I resume the system from suspend either it gets auto suspend or I manually suspend it, it resets the session, and the things opened in the previous session are closed and it is like the system had a cold boot. How do I get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like the new gpu driver doesn't support suspend properly.

Comment: @user10489 yeah, I think so. how do I overcome this?